# CRM 365: How to clear lookup through PATCH operation together with other changes?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm

CRM Dynamics 365 v9.1. Web API.

I need to update some entity record: `string` and `bool` attributes and clear some `lookup`.

I know that I can clear lookup by REST `DELETE` operation: `{{crmWebApiUrl}}contacts(03db3c0a-27e3-ec11-998d-005056918c2c)/new_operator_du_id/$ref`, but I need to do all changes as *a single transaction*.

I don't want only part of my changes to be applied in case of an error. Either all changes must be completed, or none of them (if an error occurred). Therefore, I want to make all necessary changes through a single request.

How can I do all my necessary changes through **a single** operation (*i.e. as a single transaction*)?

```
var entity = {};
entity.new_appeal = "Updated text";
entity.new_is_qualified = true;
entity["new_operator_du_id@odata.bind"] = "/new_operatorses()"; // How can I clear current value of this lookup?

var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("PATCH", Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v9.1/contacts(03db3c0a-27e3-ec11-998d-005056918c2c)", true);
req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
        req.onreadystatechange = null;
        if (this.status === 204) {
            //Success - No Return Data - Do Something
        } else {
            Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(this.statusText);
        }
    }
};
req.send(JSON.stringify(entity));
```

**UPD**

In our company is installed old managed solution CRM REST Builder in CRM Dynamics 365 v9.1. I can't install other managed solution (Dataverse REST Builder) without their allowing (to get their allowing - it is not so quickly). I have also XrmToolBox (desktop application) but when I installed Dataverse REST Builder to it then its tab is empty and it write to install managed solution instead of.

Therefore I use CRM REST Builder.

For existing `account` record I created this request by CRM REST Builder and replaced `parentaccountid@odata.bind` value by `null` and API version `8.1` to `9.1`.

But if I run this code through CRM REST Builder constructor then I get "Bad Request" response:

```
var entity = {};
entity["parentaccountid@odata.bind"] = null; // "/accounts()";

var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("PATCH", Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v9.1/accounts(32ac43be-24e6-ec11-998d-005056918c2c)", true);
req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
        req.onreadystatechange = null;
        if (this.status === 204) {
            //Success - No Return Data - Do Something
        } else {
            Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(this.statusText);
        }
    }
};
req.send(JSON.stringify(entity));
```

May be I am to edit or add some request headers?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax to clear a lookup value is to set it as null, so your code should be

`entity["new_operator_du_id@odata.bind"] = null;`

this is the code generated by Dataverse REST Builder with XHR syntax (the Guid has been changed to match the one provided by the user but with the original Guid it works).

```
var record = {};
record["parentaccountid@odata.bind"] = null; // Lookup

var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("PATCH", Xrm.Utility.getGlobalContext().getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v9.1/accounts(32ac43be-24e6-ec11-998d-005056918c2c)", true);
req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
req.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
        req.onreadystatechange = null;
        if (this.status === 204) {
            console.log("Record updated");
        } else {
            console.log(this.responseText);
        }
    }
};
req.send(JSON.stringify(record));
```

Comment: Then I get an exception: An error occurred while validating input parameters: Microsoft.OData.ODataException: The 'odata.bind' instance or property annotation has a null value. In OData, the 'odata.bind' instance or property annotation must have a non-null string value.

Comment: This is my JSON for PATCH operation: {"new_operator_du_id@odata.bind":null,"new_status":1,"new_is_qualified":false,"birthdate":"1990-02-02T21:00:00Z","firstname":"Test.FirstName.Updated","middlename":"Test.MiddleName.Updated","lastname":"Test.LastName.Updated","mobilephone":"+7-333-444-55-77","new_appeal":null}

Comment: thanks for your tests. Tomorrow I will do some tests and let you know, probably I need to update my tool as well to handle this scenario

Comment: @AndreyBushman I just did a test (parentaccountid of the account table) and I was able to set it and after clear it by just assigning null to the odata.bind property.
This is my code for reference;
var record = {};
record["parentaccountid@odata.bind"] = null;
if you can test with my tool Dataverse REST Builder just to set only this property (you add the column but don't assign a value).
Maybe the error is coming from another field in your PATCH operation?

Comment: I added UPD section in my question. Can you show me your JS-code generated by Dataverse REST Builder? I want to compare it with code generated by  CRM REST Builder.

Comment: @AndreyBushman I updated my answer, practically the only difference is how the instance url is fetched, I use the new way `Xrm.Utility.getGlobalContext().getClientUrl()` instead of the old one `Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl()`. Try to output the values of these two clienturls and see if there is a difference. As I understood from your update you are probably onpremise and connecting inside XrmToolBox with a method that is not supported by DRB (for this you get the message to download the managed solution).

Comment: Hm... I replaced `Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl()` by `Xrm.Utility.getGlobalContext().getClientUrl()` but it didn't help: I get "Bad Request" still. But I got allowing to install the managed solution Dataverse REST Builder on our Dev CRM. I will install it today and try to use your tool. If it will no help then I can write video with this problem with step by step.

Comment: If I run your code then I haven't error (bad request) but the attribute wasn't cleared.

Comment: Oh... No. You write message to console instead of alert window. So, I get bad request error in console message. Magic not happened.

Comment: @AndreyBushman I am out of ideas. When you get approval to install the managed solution of Dataverse REST Builder then you can try with it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245379/discussion-between-andrey-bushman-and-guido-preite).

Answer (score 0):

I used Dataverse REST builder (by Guido Preite) and there is a specific API call to clear a lookup through a "disassociate" WebAPI call. For example, this will remove a contact from an account:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("DELETE", Xrm.Utility.getGlobalContext().getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v9.1/accounts(11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111)/contact_customer_accounts(22222222-2222-2222-2222-222222222222)/$ref", true);
req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
req.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
        req.onreadystatechange = null;
        if (this.status === 204 || this.status === 1223) {
            console.log("Success");
        } else {
            console.log(this.statusText);
        }
    }
};
req.send();
```